# How does SQL Server determine if stored procedures are valid for "readonly" application intent?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, readonly

The `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object` function takes an object (e.g. stored procedure) and determines the properties of the first result set.

Is there a similar function that can show me if a procedure is "readonly", which could indicate that it can be used properly with `ApplicationIntent=readonly` in the connection string?

Comment: AFAIK, no. Consider that procs might contain dynamic SQL or be nested, making it a challenge to determine if the proc actually changes data.

Comment: @DanGuzman, I was thinking that if SQL Server knows when it's safe to run a proc on a secondary readonly server that it might expose that information to clients in some way. If `applicationintent` is only a hint, then I'm wondering why I wouldn't want to put it on every connection string in hopes that the server would place readonly calls on the secondaries.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.  SQL Server does not mark objects as read-only, that is set at a user rights level.  The ApplicationIntent=readonly seems to be dealing with a situation where you are running Availability Groups and have a read-only replica for reporting usually.  It would then route to that server.

[Read Only Application Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347541/what-does-applicationintent-readonly-mean-in-the-connection-string)